# How to know that we give up a print

Tags: android, printing

I'm currently developing a printer service for a specific printer.

When I'm in document preview, I can select a printer and so in that case I disconnect from the preselected printer (I'm using here BLE devices) and connect to the new one.

But I can also click on 'back' button to give up the print. And here is a problem because according to my researchs, I don't have any clear information about that action.
Even worst, the same callbacks are called in that case and if I click on print !?!
I though to systematically disconnect from the printer when I leave the preview activity and then reconnect when `onPrintJobQueued()` is called to create the job but unfortunately I have no information here about the selected printer.
So I really don't know how to do but I need to know if I confirm or not the print to eventually disconnect from the current printer to release it.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if the connection is time consuming, your PrintService should keep the connection after the printer is untracked [`onStopPrinterStateTracking`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/printservice/PrinterDiscoverySession#onstopprinterstatetracking) in case the user is just switching printers. Then it should release it in 'onDestroy' after checking that there is no job queue for this printer, by that time, you should have already received a `onPrintJobQueued()` (if any) and would know if you should keep the connection or discard it.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I don't remember what mistake I made when I first tried to disconnect in `onDestroy` but that works. Thanks.